# Mobile IP Addresses

Tags: mobile, ip

I know that when you hit a page on a site your IP gets logged and the owner can view it.
I've seen it with computers.

There can't possibly be enough IPs to cover all computers and cellphones...
So, since mobiles access by 2G, 3G, 4G, what is the IP that gets registered? Is it like PC accessing?
Do they even generate an IP?

I guess that for Wi-Fi connection they do get an IP, so what about the other signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a 3g service provider you are on their network, so the IP Address will go through a NAT firewall/router and the ip of your device will be their public address such as AT&T.

Much like your home router works. Any computer on your home network will share the IP address of the router.

Comment: Interesting. +1 for the NAT explanation.